# Openbox HiDPI scale problem

Tags: arch-linux, openbox

I installed openbox wm on my 2160x1440px 200DPI Huawei Matebook 13 laptop. But since I can't scale, applications (Firefox, Termianl, Discord etc. ) are not readable and everything is too small. How can I fix this problem? For example, I was scaling 150% when using kde.

Comment: Have you read [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI) ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I haven't been able to solve the problem yet. Everything is very small(fonts, icons, apps etc. )

Answer (score 1):

I had the most luck scaling openbox via the `Xft.dpi` setting in `~/.Xresources`
See https://thebadsleep.excus.eu/2022/05/16/openbox-hidpi-displays-and-scaling/ and the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/HiDPI)

When I set Xft.dpi to the true DPI of the monitor (not a multiple of 96) most apps (eg web browser) rendered text at an appropriate scale. Most Openbox elements (eg menus, title bars) can be separately scaled by setting the font size in `.config/openbox/rc.xml`